# Deleting Loads of Openfire users

Tags: sql, bash, chat, openfire

I have an **OpenFire chat server** running for clients. I need to delete all users who have not logged in for about 6 months. I think it will be around ~1500 users that need to be deleted. Clicking delete and confirm is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to do it via a **script** or **command line** ?